# Does Arch-Linux work well on a macbook pro?

Tags: arch-linux, macintosh

I'm considering installing it for a dualboot with osx, so is it buggy or anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few Macbook users in the Arch community. There is good documentation on the Arch wiki about installation, and a few threads in the forums describing issues and fixes.

[Macbook on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook)

[Page with detail on the aluminium model](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook_Aluminum)

Comment: My Arch Linux installation is failing because grub-install on EFI system partition fails. I think this is because the Arch Linux installer can only be used through CD as Macbook BIOS does not allow non-EFI USB boot and the booting from CD does not load the EFI kernel modules. Do you have any experience to share?

Comment: Not really; but you need to make an EFI-bootable USB image (it is described on the Wiki).